# Formtastic Does not show the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins, formtastic

i'm using formtastic i have the following

before_filter :get_client, :except => [:index,:create]

private 
   def get_client
      @client = params[:id].present? ? Client.find(params[:id]) : Client.new
   end

and an action
   def new
   end

the view is as follows

%h1 New Client
   %p
     -semantic_form_for [:admin,@client] do |f|
       =f.inputs
       =f.buttons

and i have ran the migration through rake db:migrate

The form dose not show

thanks

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with formtastic and haml because when i used erb instead it worked just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
%p -semantic_form_for
```

Should be changed to this:

```
%p =semantic_form_for
```

Notice the "=".